# jQuery load div then when link is clicked pass variables

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to load a php inside a `div1` using jquery. The code I have so far below works fine for loading the initial `div1`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").load('load.php');
});
</script>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Inside `load.php` I will have links like this below

```
<a href="load.php?id=123456">Link 1</a>
<a href="load.php?id=1234567">Link 2</a>
<a href="load.php?id=12345678">Link 3</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is on the page the `div1` is loaded, when the links load inside the `div1` I want to be able to click on the links and it will pass the `?id=` var inside the `div1` and re-load `load.php?id= var here`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").load('load.php');
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#div1").load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Adding the above would probably be the simplest way. It would take any anchor element and load it into `div1` when clicked. The `e.preventDefault()` stops the link from loading the new page.

If you have other anchor elements in there that you don't want to direct into this div, you would want to add a class to the anchor elements and then only select that class in the click handler (like `a.class` instead of `'a'`).

Comment: It works great and took your adivce to add the a.class. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#div1').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_id = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#div1').load(new_id);
});
```

This will bind the links loaded into `#div1`, using `.on()` let's it still work even though the content will be dynamic.

Then it grabs the href and loads that into `#div1`.

Comment: Please ignore the fact that this post was down voted. Someone had their feelings hurt that their answer was incorrect.